Why do transitive analyzers/source generators flow through by default despite what the documentation states?
It's mentioned in the official NuGet documentation that the default value of PrivateAssets (which specifies which assets won't "flow through" to consuming projects) for a <PackageReference> is contentfiles;analyzers;build — see this; which, as far as I understand, is supposed to mean that, by default, if:

Project A references package B
Package B references package C containing analyzers/source generators
Then the analyzers/source generators from C would not flow through to A.

This, however, doesn't seem to be the case, which I find perplexing. Here's a minimal reproduction: https://github.com/aradalvand/nuget-transitive-analyzer-test
Steps to reproduce:

git clone https://github.com/aradalvand/nuget-transitive-analyzer-test
dotnet build

Here is the ThePackage's .nuspec contents:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ThePackage</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>ThePackage</authors>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <repository type="git" />
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net8.0">
        <dependency id="Riok.Mapperly" version="3.6.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>

Notice exclude="Build,Analyzers".
However, when you run dotnet build on the repro linked above, to build the ConsumingThePackage project, you'll see that Mapperly's (an analyzer/source gen project referenced by ThePackage) source generators are actually executed for ConsumingThePackage. This is precisely against what exclude="Build,Analyzers" suggests.
What am I missing?! This is extremely surprising, given what the docs say.

this question has also been asked at NuGet: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/13813  anyone else interested, check that issue for an answer, and if it hasn't been answered yet, click the subscribe button to be notified when it is.
